# how to validate property c#

Tags: c#, try-catch

how to stop execution of method if property has null ?

my code

```
string projectName = "";
    public string _ProjectName
    {
        get { return projectName; }
        set 
        {
            try
            {
                if (value != string.Empty)
                    projectName = value;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Enter project name");
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

if projectName is not null or empty print() can executed

```
void print()
{
  MessageBox.Show(projectName);
}
```

how to do it...
thanks

Comment: If you `return;` in a void it will stop the execution. So something like `if(projectName == null || projectName == string.Empty) return;` should work.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so that the question has an actual answer. **Edit:** There we go; glad I could help you!

Comment: Just as a side note, you might want to use string.IsNullOrEmpty. It's shorter, and easier to remember :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `return;` in a void stops further execution, so working it into the code is as simple as this;

```
void print()
{
    if(projectName == null || projectName == string.Empty)
        return;
    MessageBox.Show(projectName);
}
```

This will prevent the execution of `MessageBox.Show(projectName);` if the conditions `projectName == null || projectName == string.Empty` are not met.